# Drupal - change destination for anonymous users using custom_url_rewrite_inbound?

Tags: php, drupal

Is it possible to have anonymous users (or more specifically, users without a 'member' role) be redirected from a specific menu item to an alternative node of my choosing, maybe using custom_url_rewrite_inbound?

This would then enable me to have two versions of certain pages for members and non-members (it's a site specific thing!).

Cheers.

Comment: Do you want the whole content to be different? You can do things other than redirect if you just wish to hide parts of a node.
Also are you looking to have an alternative node per node, or one accross the whole site?

Comment: I guess one solution would be to add the relevant text to a CCK field and hide that from non-members (whilst keeping the body viewable). I'd be interested to know if the redirect thing is possible though - it'd help me understand Drupal a bit more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `custom_url_rewrite_inbound()` for this would be somewhat similar to using a sledgehammer to adjust the angle of a crooked picture - can be done, but it is cumbersome and comes with the risk of causing some damage ;)

A better solution depends on what you want to achieve exactly, and how often (i.e. for how many nodes) you need to do it, so you should explain your scenario a bit more detailed. Some possible approaches include:

- 'Enrich' your nodes with data/fields for both versions, and adjust the actual output depending on user role

  - If you use CCK, you could use the fields permission settings for this.
  - You might also do some adjustments in the theme layer via custom node templates.
  - Another approach would be via `hook_nodeapi()` (operation 'view') from a custom module, removing entries from the content array depending on user role.
- Provide explicit redirection to other nodes depending on user role (your explicit question)

  - replace the standard node page callback via `hook_menu_alter()` with a custom one. Within that, you check the role. If it is ok, you just call the standard callback, else you issue a `drupal_goto()` (based on some general logic, if possible).
  - If the 'special' cases are rare, you could do this via `hook_nodeapi()` as well, again reacting to operation 'view', but you'd need to make sure that you only do this for node page views, not if the node is just displayed as a teaser along with others.
  - Implement `hook_init()` in a custom module, check the path (`arg()` or `$_GET['q']`) and the role, issue `drupal_goto()` as needed. (Beware of cached pages - if you need to cover those, use `hook_boot()` instead).

Etc. ... - I'm sure there are more options, so you might want to provide more details on your problem/goal/scenario to allow for a more precise suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom menu handler for that link, and then in the function that runs that handler you could have something like

```
if (user->role == 'access granted') {

  // do stuff

} else {

drupal_goto('anonymouspage');

}
```